# Where can I find historical hourly cloudcover/skycover data for specific coordinates in Northeast America?

Tags: data-request, usa, weather, climate

I am looking for historical hourly weather data, specifically cloud cover for specific coordinates.

I have used Darksky API and it gives cloudcover as a value between 0 and 1, but I do not trust their model for coming up with these values.

I have tried to look for any dataset from national weather services, but their websites are so confusing that it is super hard to find one.

I am looking for the data from a reliable source that gives me cloudcover as a value between 0 and 1 or in terms of NWS skycover forecast terms (clear, mostly clear, partly cloudy, mostly cloudy, cloudy).

Comment: would anything here work? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-data-set-real-time-and-archived-nexrad-weather-data/ You say "cloud cover" but  perhaps from the radar or reflectivity you could derive cloud cover.

Comment: Another is the "sky cover survey" from https://www7.ncdc.noaa.gov/CDO/cdoselect.cmd?datasetabbv=SUMMARIES&countryabbv=&georegionabbv=&resolution=0

Comment: thanks for the response. I would prefer to avoid the first route as it significantly add to the work that I have to do, but my approach will be open to questions and non-standard. I have looked at the second group of datasets you suggested, but they only give data for a few locations which are far away from my desired coordinates.